# Passing a variable in the require in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using javascript and node.js . I have the following lines in my code :

```
var countryName = "Turkey";
var jsonPath = '../'+countryName+'/PersonalDetails.json';
console.log(jsonPath);
var PersonalDetails = require(jsonPath);
```

This gives the error : Cannot find module '../Turkey/PersonalDetails.json'

but when I use

```
var PersonalDetails = require('../Turkey/PersonalDetails.json');
```

it works fine. What am I missing?

Also attaching my json file for reference.

```
{
    "fields":[
                {
                    "fieldType":"Radio",
                    "fieldLabel":"Relevance to the transaction :",
                    "disclosureField":""    ,
                    "fieldList":["One carrying out the transaction","One on behalf of him/her the transaction is carried out","Indirect Relevance"]
                },
                {
                    "fieldType":"Radio",
                    "fieldLabel":"Is ID Card False",
                    "disclosureField":"",
                    "fieldList":["Yes","No"]
                },
                {
                    "fieldType":"Radio",
                    "fieldLabel":"Sex :",
                    "disclosureField":"gender",
                    "fieldList":["Male","Female","Unknown"]
                },
                {
                    "fieldType":"TextInput",
                    "fieldLabel":"First Name",
                    "disclosureField":"identity.first_name",
                    "fieldList":[]
                },
                {
                    "fieldType":"TextInput",
                    "fieldLabel":"SurName",
                    "disclosureField":"identity.last_name",
                    "fieldList":[]
                },
                {
                    "fieldType":"NumberInput",
                    "fieldLabel":"TR ID Number :",
                    "disclosureField":"",
                    "fieldList":[]
                },
                {
                    "fieldType":"NumberInput",
                    "fieldLabel":"Tax Number :",
                    "disclosureField":"",
                    "fieldList":[]
                },
                {
                    "fieldType":"TextInput",
                    "fieldLabel":"Mother's Name :",
                    "disclosureField":"",
                    "fieldList":[]
                },
                {
                    "fieldType":"TextInput",
                    "fieldLabel":"Father's Name :",
                    "disclosureField":"",
                    "fieldList":[]
                },
                {
                    "fieldType":"TextInput",
                    "fieldLabel":"Nationality :",
                    "disclosureField":"nationality",
                    "fieldList":[]
                },
                {
                    "fieldType":"TextInput",
                    "fieldLabel":"Occupation :",
                    "disclosureField":"occupation",
                    "fieldList":[]
                },
                {
                    "fieldType":"TextInput",
                    "fieldLabel":"Additional Information :",
                    "disclosureField":"",
                    "fieldList":[]
                }
                ]
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and it works fine. Maybe your version of node has an issue are you trying this with the latest version?

Comment: I am using version 5.10.1 . I guess that is the latest version.

Comment: The latest in the site is  6.1.0 but its ok I tried this on 5.9.1 and it worked fine. Maybe this is an os related issue which do you have? I tried this on windows 7

Comment: Yeah I'm also using windows 7

Comment: I think there is an issue with your json file did you try to validate it? Also notice that if it's empty it is also a problem, I just tried with an empty file and it gave an error

Comment: I validated it.It looks fine, also it works fine if I give the path explicitly in qoutes require('../Turkey/PersonalDetails.json'); Added the json for reference

Answer (score 0):

You can define a path linke this:

```
var path = require(__dirname + "yourpath");
```

Let me know if this helped

EDIT:

```
var jsonPath = require(__dirname + '/../' + countryName + '/PersonalDetails.json');
```

Comment: Can you clarify it based on my code. What exactly has to be used?

Comment: /views\suspects/../Turkey/PersonalDetails.json. This is the pathit is getting if I use the above line . Do I need to use '\' instead of '/' ??

Comment: /views\suspects/ you see there is a wrong slash, i guess you need to fix this

Comment: but the /views\suspects comes from the _dirname . The value of _dirname is /views\suspects

Comment: Try var jsonPath = require(__dirname + '/' + countryName + '/PersonalDetails.json');

Comment: did you try to put ' ' arround Turkey instead of ""